# Binding to multiple indexers

Tags: wpf, binding, windows-phone, indexed-properties

I am trying to bind an indexed property with two indexers. The property looks like this

```cs
public Item this[int x, int y]
{
  get { return _items[x, y]; }
  set { _items[x, y] = value; }
}
```

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx, it is possible to bind against indexed properties like that

```cs
<object Path="propertyName[index,index2...]" .../>
```

There is even an example:

```cs
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding ColorGrid[20,30].SolidColorBrushResult}" .../>
```

However when I try to access that property in XAML like that:

```cs
<Image Source="{Binding Items[0,0].Image}" />
```

I get an error in the designer:

> The unnamed argument "0].Image" must appear before named arguments.

It seems to interpret 0].Image as the next argument. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the `{Binding}` markup extension - which has a `delimiter` which is `,`.

To work around that you can use the following notation...

```
<TextBox Width="100" Height="100">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="MyIndexer[1,1]" />
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Or use the 'escaped' `,` with `\` - which is also in that link (but somehow they're getting over fact that their original notation doesn't work).

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyIndexer[2\,2]}" Width="100" Height="100" />
```

Note that indexer, multi-dimentional array syntax is like this :)...

```
public string this[int x, int y]
{
    get { return _items[x][y]; }
    set { _items[x][y] = value; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works within the <Binding> tag. As for escaping, I tried that already, but then the parameters seem to be interpreted as a single string parameter and the binding doesn't work with the error message "Parameter count mismatch".

Comment: you're welcome - yes, they seem to have made their example for this `Path` like I did first - doesn't work w/o escaping it.

Comment: brilliant been hunting for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone is not a WPF, it is mostly Silverlight, and Silverlight does not support [Indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645024%28v=vs.95%29.aspx/html#indexdata):

> - Only one-dimensional array indexing is supported.

You can try to fix this by:

a) Try to implement something like `Items[0][0]`, so `Items[0]` will give you an array to which you again can apply indexer.

b) Try to implement this logic with `IValueConverter`.

Comment: Actually I get the same behavior in WPF.