# Binding multiple index from a collection in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, indexing, collections, binding

Despite having read similar questions, I could not find any one that worked well in my case.

Basically, in order to extend the functionality of the TableRow class, I created a new one in which I have registered a DependencyProperty to clear the cells, and according to [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path(v=vs.110).aspx), I am trying to bind two index from a collection, as follows:

```
<my:myExtendedClass myProperty="{Binding Path=MyCollection[index1,index2]}">
```

However, I get the following error when I try to pass more than one index:

> Error in Template: 'Unexpected token 'String' in rule: 'MarkupExtension ::= '{' TYPENAME (Arguments)? @'}'', in '{Binding Path=MyCollection[index1,index2]}'.'

Other approach would be bind the whole object `MyCollection`, but, in this way, I would not know which items I have to check each time I call the method.

So, how should I proceed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865289/binding-to-multiple-indexers

Comment: Hi @Karmacon! I had already read the post you mentioned, but, unfortunately, it did not help me, because the guy is trying to retrieve a value from a multi-dimensional array. However, in my case, I am trying to retrieve several values from a one-dimensional array :)

Comment: You will need to be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to filter the data in the collection? Or bind to an entire collection?

Comment: It would be helpful to show us what the collection looks like and what the extended class looks like.

Comment: As I have to call this class many times, each time I have to pass only the items that I need, such as `index1` and `index2`. Concretely, I have registered a new DependencyProperty of TableRow to clear the cells if the items passed as arguments are empty :)